# For which value(s) of a and b is the function defined by, Calculus help?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Could someone aid me in finding the answer to this question?  No need to sketch the graph.

[image]

Comment: Step 1: Can you find conditions for the function to be continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Compare Left Limit and Right Limit at $1$ as they need to be equal for the function to be differentiable at $1$.